# Extracting Y only (of YUV420p) frame from an MP4 file using fmpeg?

Tags: python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, mp4, yuv

My main objective is to extract the *I'th*, *I+1'th* (next), *I-1'th* (previous) frames in the form of Y only (of YUV 420) from an mp4 video. The procedure which I am using right now is

1. I extracted the list of all the I frames from a video using the command - `ffprobe "input.mp4" -show_frames | grep  'pict_type=I' -A 1 > frame_info.txt`
2. Next, I used a python script to parse through this txt file to find the numbers of all of the **I frames** and then extracting all of the frames using the command - `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select='eq(n\,{1}),setpts=N/25/TB,extractplanes=y' -vsync 0 -pix_fmt gray {1}.yuv` This is happening via a subprocess call from python.
3. This is working fine for small resolution videos like 240p or 480p but as soon as I move to 1080p videos the **time to extract even a single frame increases exponentially.** As the ffmpeg seeks to that frame number to extract it and it has to decode the mp4 file till that point.

I have a lot of 1080p files and I was looking to decrease the time. The solution which I was thinking was to extract all of the Y frames (of YUV 420) from mp4 and then selecting only I frames as I've got the list of all of the I frames from **step 1.**. The command I am using for this is - `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "fps=59.94" -pix_fmt gray file_name.yuv`

- The **problem** with the above code is that it **continuously appends the to yuv file only** but I want an individual y file for one frame of the mp4 video.
- My restriction is to use FFmpeg only as FFmpeg's Y value is matching with what I want.

TL:DR - I want to extract the Y part only (of YUV 420p) from an mp4 video. The y frames are the I'th and I-1th and I+1th frames.

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

In step 1, instead of storing the frame numbers, store the pts_time.

Then, in step 2, run

```
ffmpeg -copyts -ss X -i input.mp4 -vf select='eq(t\,X),extractplanes=y' -vsync 0 -pix_fmt gray -vframes 1 {1}.yuv
```

where X is the pts_time.